# Making links responsive on an HTML page

Tags: html, css, web

I'm making a fairly simple website, and i'm having some trouble due to being new to this. I have it so it's a responsive website, but adding links to websites that are a bit long wont automatically chunk into smaller sections to fit on the screen, but just run off the screen and out of the container.

What do i need to do to make it so my links scale responsively on mobile devices with the rest of my website? The rest of the paragraph acts responsively based on the screen size, but if i add a link that is somewhat long, it will just run straight off the screen since there are no spaces for it to use as a break. How can i fix this? text-overflow?

Thanks.

Comment: Can we have some code a fiddle would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that a very long string (without spaces) is causing this problem.

Use the CSS `word-wrap` property.

```
a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) for more information.